# function in child class getting error in java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

IDE showing an error in the line commented as function in child class is getting an error look at he code below.Showing error in intellij.

```
class Movie
{
    public Movie()
    {
        System.out.println("This is movie");
        System.out.println("This is number");
    }

}

class Jaws extends Movie
{
    public Jaws()
    {
        System.out.println("this is jaws");
    }

    public void plot()//Showing Error here
    {
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public class Lec74 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Movie movie = abs();
        movie.plot();
    }

    public static Movie abs() {
        return new Jaws();
    }
}
```

Comment: // showing error here ... can you be a bit more specific? also, reading up on naming conventions would make your code a lot easier to read.
now this: public static movie abs() { will cause problems.

Comment: Post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. 
you cannot do 
`movie Movie = abs()`

if abs is a static method, then you need to call it this way-

`movie.abs();`

and the way to call plot() would be-

`movie Movie = new movie();
Movie.plot()`

You should definitely take a look at head first java to understand the basic OOP concepts in simplest way.